# Post Bundle is not working in Custom Chrome tab

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to send some data in as a post request in Custom chrome tab but it not working but same request is working in WebView. Please tell me is there any solution. Code is given below. Thanks in advance

With WebView

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.postUrl(mURL, (postHit + "userInfo=iamuser&Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

With Custom Chrome tab

```
Bundle headers = new Bundle();
headers.putString("userInfo", "iamuser");
headers.putString("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
headers.putString("charset", "utf-8");
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build();
customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(android.provider.Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, headers);
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, uri);
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible. Chrome Custom Tabs always uses a GET request.

Another approach would be to programmatically make the POST request and then display the URL that is returned.